# search functionality in BIRT Report viewer

Tags: birt

How can I give **text-based search functionality** to search entered keyword and highlight if keyword found in my BIRT report viewer?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your report viewer. The default report viewer is your default browser (used in the preview Tab of Birt). In most browsers you can use <kbd>strg</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> to search for and highlight a text. Use Chrome-Browser to highlight all occurrences of a word  simultaneously.